# Is there any way to use Siri for home control via own app?

Tags: ios, sirikit, homekit

I have a list of termostats, which I should control via mine app. Access to them should be provided and removed dynamically during app work. Also I need to control them via Siri commands. Is there any way to connect mine app to Siri? I don't see any suitable domain for that [in list](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit#topics).

I know, that Siri can do it via Home Kit by default. According [to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/HomeKitDeveloperGuide/WritingtotheHomeKitDatabase/WritingtotheHomeKitDatabase.html), I can create home / room / add accessory and share them programmatically, but inside of app.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to do "access stuff" on server side? Especially, how about removing access without manual interruption?
2. How about Apple Home not-compatible devices with remote control only via server? Is there any way to access them via Siri -> Mine app?

Comment: Have you looked into Siri Shortcuts https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/ ?

Comment: @Losiowaty thank you for advice. According to documentation, it can be possible solution. I will check it in a few days and notify in this question about result